# how to display formatted String from console.log to an html div

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

Say I have a formatted string str written in my backend java code like this :

```
name    : xxx       company : qwe
address : yyy       age     : asd
country : zzz
```

now I managed to display it on the browser console via

```
console.log(str);
```

and when I checked it is also formatted just the way it is

```
name    : xxx       company : qwe
address : yyy       age     : asd
country : zzz
```

but when I use Jquery to show it in a div in my html file, say for example

```
$('.divclass').text(str);
```

it will just be one line

```
name    : xxx       company : qweaddress : yyy       age     : asdcountry : zzz
```

this is all expected, but I was wondering if there is an implementation where I could possibly display the console.log to my html tag and still keep the format that I had before, instead of having to format it again, I guess my question is if there is a way to present console.log to the html in my case.

Comment: You can try the `<pre>` preformatted text i.e. `$('.divclass').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `<pre>`-tag or (recommended): You can replace every `\n` in the string with `<br />`.

```
str = str.replace("\n", "<br />");
```

You have to do that, because web browsers don't display normal line-breaks by themselves. You either have to use the `<br />`-tag or a special tag like `<pre>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `\n` with `<br>` and put the string (wrapped into the `<pre>` tag) in the div as inner html.

```js
var str = "name    : xxx       company : qwe\n"+
"address : yyy       age     : asd\n"+
"country : zzz    \n";

console.log(str);

str = str.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");

$(".divclass").html("<pre>"+str+"</pre>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divclass">
</div>
```